# Multiple copies of the same content shown due to voting

Tags: views, rating

I have made an image gallery using views. I want to create a vote option for each image. I used the Rate module and I've created a rate button which looks something like this

[image]

I used the yes/no widget and changed the option to this
[image]

In my gallery view I've selected the `Content:Votes` relationship and changed the 
`value type` to `options` 
and `vote tag` to `normal vote`

The problem is multiple copies of the same content appear in the gallery when the votes are increased. How can I fix this issue? or is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Try with this relationship - Content:Vote Result, Value Type: Points, and Aggregation function: Total Score

Comment: I tried..its not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it at least in 4 different ways that I can think of:

1. You can have a quick fix if you change the show to Content | Teaser or any other display of show: content
2. You can enable `Use aggregation:Yes` under Advanced menu.
3. Check if any of your fields have multiple values, like more than 1 images in your case which is a gallery. and use `grouping fields` to fix it.
4. in your multi value field (probably your image field) under `Multiple field settings` check `Display all values in the same row` and then beneath the fields, set Display `1` value(s)  starting from `0` and you should be good to go.

**Update:** 
5. Use [Views Grouping Row Limit](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_limit_grouping) module to limit the output of each grouped row.

Comment: 1. I don't want it to be displayed that way. Cause I have other fields like colorbox for example. Even when I tried it, the duplicate copies were still showing
2. When I did Use aggregation:Yes, its throwing this error SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax

Comment: I'm working on 3. and 4.

Comment: This is probably a noob question but how do I check if the fields have multiple values

Comment: Well did you upload more than 1 file for any of the fields? like your image field? if so, it means it has more than 1 value

Comment: No..I didn't. Only one file's uploaded for each field

Comment: Okay still try #4 for each of your fields and see if it works, if it didn't you should go with #3

Comment: Where do I find Multiple field settings? In views, I don't see that option

Comment: click on your field, there's a fieldset there, click on it to expand

Comment: I don't see it. Here's a screenshot http://i.imgur.com/JgktlZj.png. Am i looking in the right place

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17878/discussion-between-nabeela-and-sohail).

Answer (score 4):

Hmm.. On the right side, go to **Advanced**, **Other**, then **Query Settings**.

Select the checkbox for "Distinct", and click Apply.

According to the help note:

> This will make the view display only distinct items. If there are
>   multiple identical items, each will be displayed only once. You can
>   use this to try and remove duplicates from a view, though it does not
>   always work. Note that this can slow queries down, so use it with
>   caution.

There are more options past that if it doesn't work.. making it more strict, for example.  But as the help note mentions.. this doesn't always work.

Comment: That didn't work :(

Comment: This kinda never worked for me, even though that it supposed to work, did you ever get this Query Settings working?

Comment: Oh no.  :(  I've used it before in other queries and it has helped. @Sohail's multi value field sounds promising though!

Comment: If it is not working then select `Pure Distinct` too.

Answer (score 0):

I had to use the Views Distinct module. Added NID to list of fields, exclude from display and then use filter repeat in the Views Distinct Settings.  Funny thing is I had to increase the number of items in the pager to more than the actual number of images, else not all show up.